# Delete duplicate values from pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to delete duplicate values from a dataframe and its not deleting as expected. Here is the code I tried....

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Alphabet':['A','B','C','A'],
                 'Number':[1,2,3,1]})
print(df)
df.drop_duplicates(['Alphabet'],keep='last')
print(df)
```

Comment: You forget assign `df = df.drop_duplicates(['Alphabet'],keep='last')`

Comment: Or `df.drop_duplicates(['Alphabet'],keep='last', inplace=True)`